# How to find what are the uicontrols like uibutton or uitoolbar added to uinavigationbar and self.view?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have to identify what are the subview of UInavigationbar and self.view or window for all the viewcontrollers in the application when i visit that view.How can we do that.How to identify if the control is of type uibarbutton item or uitoolbar??Sample code is available below.

```
for (UIView *tempview in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([[tempview superclass] isSubclassOfClass:[UIControl class]] || [tempview isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]] || [tempview isKindOfClass:[UIView class]] || [[tempview superclass] isSubclassOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
        NSLog(@"Desc : %@",[tempview description]);            
    }
}
```

Comment: This functionality is implemented by SAP for displaying help on each control functionality.. I think you need more description for this requirement..

Comment: Please give positive votes,This is my first task.. i want to get answer for this question

Comment: still any confustion in question and answer?? please correct me if anything is wrong.

Comment: I have updated the question.please help me in retaining positive votes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find different controls by using following code

```
-(void)getSubviews:(UIView *)parent{
   for(UIView *subview in parent.subviews){
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]){
              //tableview
        }else if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
             //UIbutton
        }
        //so on
   }
}
```

But as per your requirement I afraid you will be able to add button for all the controls..

Comment: yes.That's the difficult task in this..